# Count of SOQL Statements used in Debug logs

Tags: soql, governorlimits, debugging

I keep searching and I can't seem to find it, I need to output the number of SOQL Statements used at a given point in my class (to make my class more efficient), something like:

`System.debug('Count of SOQL Queries used: '+__);`

I know it's possible but I can't find a link to the docs.

Thanks to @Adrian Larson for quickly solving my mental block!!!

**[Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the `Limits` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm):

```
Integer queriesUsed = Limits.getQueries();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll add documentation to my original question